# How to fix an XML sitemap that Google says doesn't properly declare the namespace?

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap, xml, sitemap-index

I am getting error on Google search console for XML Sitemap.

**Sitemap.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
    <loc>https://example.com/channels/</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
</urlset>
```

> **Error**: Your Sitemap or Sitemap index file doesn't properly declare the
> namespace.

[image]

**Sitemap Index XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
<loc>https://example.com/sitemap_main.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

> **Error** : Your Sitemap or Sitemap index file doesn't properly declare
> the namespace.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters.  Have you googled it?

Comment: @RohitGupta Yes, Googled a lot and Asked in Google Community forum. No fix, i asked here.

Comment: @RohitGupta Please don't ask "Have you google it?"   Even questions with easy to find answers are fine to ask here. You and I are here to answer questions, not to nudge the asker to try to find the answer themselves.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller i believe my mistake is not adding `www` in url. i am using `http://sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9` but when i checked different website sitemap they all using `http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9`. i am not sure if `www` can make can issue

Comment: @MehulKumar, I think that's it, try with the www

Comment: If you find that works, you can answer your own question. using the answer box below here.